# Why setting state to a constant triggers rerender two times?

Tags: reactjs

Demonstration:

https://codesandbox.io/s/2zkxyk31oy

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  console.log("render");
  let [val, setVal] = useState(0);
  return <button onClick={() => setVal(1)}>go</button>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

What I expect to see is two render calls: the initial one, and the one caused by the state change.

The third `setState` call should have no effect, since react bails out of rendering if the state hasn't changed. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update

What exactly is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The doc link you provided states:

> Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t unnecessarily go “deeper”

It appears the behaviour is consistent with what the doc says. In order to test that, you can check if child components are being rendered. Something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  console.log("render");
  let [val, setVal] = useState(0);
  return <button onClick={() => setVal(1)}><Child/></button>;
}

function Child() {
  console.log('render the child')
  return <span>go</span>
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

The result in the console now is:

```
render 
render the child 
render 
render the child 
render
```